# Moving vertex of a mesh along z Axis

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am trying to move along z axis a vertex of a mesh. The mesh is similar to a sphere, not a sphere but similar. It´s a imported mesh from blender.

The problem is that when I move a vertice/vertex along z Axis it is like world coordinates and I would need to move it along an axis pointing to the center of the mesh.

For example in a 3d model software I can change the axis to normal to get this effect.

I have checked that I can get this working with **multiplyScalar** method but it doesn´t work well because I need to tween the effect and I should move the position.

What is the three.js aproach to get it?

PD: sorry for noob question. I have worked with javascript for years but I haven´t been able to learn this concept in books/tutorials of three.js and I´m not sure what is the way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to solve this problem:

```
            var box1 = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000})
            );
            scene.add(box1);

            var box2 = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00})
            );
            box2.position.set(100,100,100);
            scene.add(box2);
            var box3 = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff})
            );
            box3.position.set(100,100,100);
            scene.add(box3);

            var direction = box1.position.clone().sub(box2.position).normalize();
            var move = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,100);
            var moveCorrected = direction.multiplyScalar( move.length() );
            box3.position.add(moveCorrected);
```

[Example there](http://jsfiddle.net/exiara/10zcn021/) - green cube moved from blue and red in the same direction by initial vector of 0,0,100.